# How to resolve E/Volley: BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to access the REST API that return a JSON object with HTTP 200 status codes. It works correctly with Postman but when i request from Volley it gives me below error every time.

```
E/Volley: [3766] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for API
```

This is my code

```
private void getListData() {
        showDialog();
        String url = "http://www.**********.com";
        HashMap<String, String> requestParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        requestParams.put("SecurityKey",
                Preferences.getSecurityKey(AppointmentsListActivity.this));
        requestParams.put("ToDate", endDate);
        requestParams.put("FromDate", startDate);
        Log.i(TAG, "JSON : " + new JSONObject(requestParams));
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, new JSONObject(requestParams),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        closeDialog();
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse : " + response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                closeDialog();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
              //  headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); also use this but didn't work
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, "get_data");
    }
```

My App class code

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = App.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static App mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }


    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
E/Volley: [3946] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://www.********.com
E/com.android.myappointments.ui.activity.AppointmentsListActivity: Error: null
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8653b40
```

i didn't show my Api service

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you used postman in system browser? or mobile?

Comment: I my system browser. @SathishKumarJ

Comment: but you are using Volley in mobile. may be your internet speed is slow when compare to system

Comment: HTTP code 400 means 'bad request'. I don't know which API your using, but the fact that Postman works could be related to credentials that are possibly stored in your browser or the you're missing POST parameters when you use volley

Answer (score 0):

Remove Header

```
 @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
          //  headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); also use this but didn't work
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

And Add Retry policy in your application class:

```
 public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 1, 1));
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

See sample code here - [VolleyExample](https://github.com/rkoshti/VolleyWithGSON)